# R function for setwd to google drive

Tags: r

I wish to set my working directory in R to my google drive (G:) for a project. Unfortunately, when

```
setwd("G:\.abcfolder\blahblah\blahblah")
```

returns an error message as

> '.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""G:."

This "escape" is standard in google drive paths- I am unsure how to proceed short of trying to manually change the path name itself.

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: I recommend that you do not use `setwd()`, take a look at the package `here`

Comment: Sorry- that is not a working link

Comment: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Comment: haha OK you mean the package here, not a link there

Comment: @ViníciusFélix here gives the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, strings use a single backslash as an escape character for things that can't be typed.  So in your string `"G:\.abcfolder\blahblah\blahblah"` you have characters `\.` (which doesn't exist) and `\b` (which is the control character that "rang the bell" on old terminals).

If you actually want a backslash in a string, you need to write it as two.  So your path should be `"G:\\.abcfolder\\blahblah\\blahblah"`.  When you call `print()` on this string, you'll see the quotes and doubled backslashes, but if you call `cat()` you'll only see what was there:  no quotes and single backslashes.

I don't know if you can call `setwd()` on that path, but there's a good chance that `setwd("G:\\.abcfolder\\blahblah\\blahblah")` will work if anything will work.  Another possibility is to use forward slashes instead, e.g. `setwd("G:/.abcfolder/blahblah/blahblah")`.

One oddity you might not be aware of:  on Unix-alike systems, there's only one working directory, but on Windows, you have a separate working directory for each volume.  R uses the Unix convention, so the `cmd`-shell equivalent of `setwd("G:\\.abcfolder\\blahblah\\blahblah")` is actually two commands:

```
G:
cd \.abcfolder\blahblah\blahblah
```